# Easier way to create pandas multi-column Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Right now I create a [multi-column DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) as following:

```
column1 = ["A","B","C"]
column2 = ["a","b","c"]
tuples = []
for c1 in column1:
    for c2 in column2:
        tuples += [(i1,i2)]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Large index', 'Small index'])        
q = pd.DataFrame(index = t, columns = columns )
q.loc[:, ("A","a")] = 1
```

Now I wonder: Is there an easier syntax to deliver the same?
Cheers!

## edit: Corrected typos.

Comment: sample `index1`, `index2`?

Comment: Do you mean multi-*index* frame?

Comment: Are you after `MultiIndex.from_product`?

Comment: No output dataframe, missing parameters doesn't make a reproducable example and a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), which *makes a MultiIndex from the cartesian product of multiple iterables*:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([column1, column2], names=['Large index', 'Small index']))

#Large index    A           B           C
#Small index    a   b   c   a   b   c   a   b   c
```